# Get start date and start time for Outlook appointment from two cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to get the start date and the start time for an Outlook appointment from two cells in Excel.

The following is only working for one of the cells:

```vb
Sub Email()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMeet AS Outlook.Appointment
Set OutApp = Outlook.Application
Set OutMeet = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

With Outmeet
    .Start = Range("X1").Value
End With

End Sub
```

My two cells show the following.
A1 = '25/12/2021'
A2 = '7:30 AM'

Comment: Convert the value of both cells into a date variable using `CDate` and pass the variable to `Start` property.

Comment: Sorry I'm rather new to using VBA could you show an example of how this would be done?

Comment: Edit your question and provide several sample data of your 2 cells value for us to help you. We can't see what you don't show. @studentuni998

Comment: I have updated so my whole code is shown. My two cells show the following. A1 = '25/12/2021' A2 = '7:30 AM'.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Email()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMeet As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set OutApp = Outlook.Application
    
    Set OutMeet = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    With OutMeet
        .Display
        .Start = Range("A1").Value & " " & Format(Range("A2").Value, "h:mm")
        .End = Range("B1").Value & " " & Format(Range("B2").Value, "h:mm")
        '.Duration = 90
    End With
End Sub
```